# overlaying image libreoffice document onto text libreoffice document

Tags: openoffice.org

Ok, I'd like to know if it is possible to overlay two openoffice/libreoffice documents (writer or impress).

For instance, I have document1 and document2 and want pages 1 of each document to give page 1 of new document.

Basically, document1 contains the text of the presentation and document2 contains the images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to combine two documents so that the pages match.  See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&p=353295 for a discussion.

If you want to insert an image at a specific location on each page, then you could try writing a basic or python macro to cut and paste from document2 into document1.

Comment: That's a interesting way to do it. Did not know about that. The script will scan all the images of one document and paste them at the same locations in the document containing text.